# syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

What am I missing in my sql command?

```
public class PhoneDal extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = Constants.DB_NAME;

    public static final String BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE = "BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE";

    public PhoneDal(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE "+ BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE +
                        " ( "+ KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "
                        + KEY_PHONE+" TEXT, "
                        + KEY_IS_BLOCKED+" BIT," +
                        " UNIQUE "+ KEY_PHONE+" )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE);
    }
```

and the error is

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "KEY_PHONE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, KEY_PHONE TEXT, KEY_IS_BLOCKED BIT, UNIQUE KEY_PHONE )
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the value of the String `CREATE_BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE` (you really should learn the Java naming conventions) and paste it's value into your question.

Comment: For your reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error for defining unique field 
Use this `KEY_PHONE + " TEXT UNIQUE"` instead

Column definition in sqlite:
[image: Column definition]

Comment: Or even better, use spaces properly - `KEY_PHONE + " TEXT UNIQUE"`

Answer (score 3):

`UNIQUE` columns must be defined in parens. Change

```
" UNIQUE "+ KEY_PHONE+" )";
```

to

```
" UNIQUE ("+ KEY_PHONE+") )";
```

Comment: but @Mousa solved my problem differently and it worked. how come it's different than yours?

Comment: This way defines a table constraint and the UNIQUE can apply to more than one column. Mousa's way defines a column constraint. I answered like this since your question was using a table constraint incorrectly. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html